Why do I get a SEGFAULT when I try to sort an array of integers using K & R code examples?
I'm trying to work my way through The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition, and I can't get my head around exactly what is happening in the following code.
The example from the book works just fine when sorting an array of strings but I get a SEGFAULT when sorting an array of integers.
I know it is probably because the integer value is being used as a pointer to a value and I think the problem happens when swap() is called for the first time but I can't work out how to fix the problem.  (I don't want to have two separate quick sort functions).
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int atoi (char s_string[])

/* See K+R Ed 2 Page 43 */
{
    int i_count, i_number;

    i_number = 0;
    for (i_count = 0; s_string[i_count] >= '0' && s_string[i_count] <= '9'; i_count++)
        i_number = 10 * i_number + s_string[i_count] - '0';
    return i_number;
}

static void swap (void *p_array[], int i_left, int i_right)

/* See K+R Ed 2 Page 96 */
{
    void* p_temp;
    p_temp = p_array[i_left];
    p_array[i_left] = p_array[i_right];
    p_array[i_right] = p_temp;
}

void qsort (void *p_array[], int i_left, int i_right, int (*compare)(void *, void*))

/* See K+R Ed 2 Page 120 */
{
    int i_count, i_last;

    if (i_left >= i_right) return; /* Do nothing */
    swap (p_array, i_left, (i_left + i_right)/2);
    i_last = i_left;
    for (i_count = i_left +1; i_count <= i_right; i_count++)
        if ((*compare)(p_array[i_count], p_array[i_left]) < 0)
            swap(p_array, ++i_last, i_count);
    swap (p_array, i_left, i_last);
    qsort (p_array, i_left, i_last -1, compare);
    qsort (p_array, i_last +1, i_right, compare);
}

int numcmp (char *s_left, char *s_right)

/* See K+R Ed 2 Page 121 */
{
    int i_left, i_right;

    i_left = atoi (s_left);
    i_right = atoi (s_right);

    if (i_left < i_right)
        return -1;
    else if (i_left > i_right)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int cmpint (int i_left, int i_right)
{
   return (i_left > i_right) - (i_left < i_right);
}

int cmpstr (char *s_left, char *s_right)
{
    return strcmp (s_left, s_right);
}

void prtint (int *array, size_t i_size)
{
    size_t i_count;
    if (i_size > 0)
    {
        printf ("(%d", array[0]);
        for (i_count = 1; i_count < i_size; i_count++)
            printf (", %d", array[i_count]);
    }
    printf (")\n");
}

void prtstr (char * const *array, size_t i_size)
{
    size_t i_count;
    if (i_size > 0)
    {
        printf ("(%s", array[0]);
        for (i_count = 1; i_count < i_size; i_count++)
            printf (", %s", array[i_count]);
    }
    printf (")\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int i_numbers[] = {INT_MAX, 5, 9, 4, 8, 3, 7, 10, 2, 1, 6, INT_MIN};
    char *s_strings[] = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine" };
    int i_size;

    i_size = sizeof(s_strings)/sizeof(s_strings[0]);
    prtstr (s_strings, i_size);
    qsort ((void **)s_strings, 0, i_size -1, (int (*)(void *, void*))cmpstr);
    prtstr (s_strings, i_size);

    i_size = sizeof(i_numbers)/sizeof(i_numbers[0]);
    prtint (i_numbers, i_size);
    qsort ((void **)i_numbers, 0, i_size -1, (int (*)(void *, void*))cmpint);
    prtint (i_numbers, i_size);

}


The immediate thing that jumps out at me is that you are using cmpstr not only for strings, but for integers as well. Surely, that is not intentional. It will certainly not work. I haven't looked beyond that typo level bug.

"I don't want to have two separate quick sort functions" Then don't attempt to sort arrays of different types. Different types require different comparison routines as they are compared differently. That is why qsort takes a comparison routine as a parameter, so you just have to provide the correct comparison routine. Otherwise you would have to write a different sort routine for each case.

Bludgeoning the types of the comparison function in qsort((void **)s_strings, 0, i_size -1, (int (*)(void *, void*))cmpstr); is not a good idea.  The function will be called with two void pointer arguments; if it expects two other types, you are running into undefined behaviour, which is Not A Good Thing™.  You should write the comparison functions with the interface that (your) qsort() expects and then cast the arguments appropriately inside the comparator.  It probably won't go wrong, but the cast is ugly as sin, which indicates something is not as clean as it should be.

Note, too, that this implementation of qsort() has a different interface from the one defined by the C standard (C11 §7.22.5.2 The qsort function — where the interface is void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));.  It would be better if the function had been given a different name (to avoid confusion with the standard qsort()).

The general rule of thumb for beginners is to never use casts at any place in their code. There's a lot of subtle crap about the C type system that needs to be taken in account when doing so.

@Jonathan Leffler -- I agree you you - it isn't pretty.
However,  I suspect the the way the qsort() function was defined in K&R was partly to illustrate the complexity.
The differences between the regular qsort() function and the implementation in K&R is the reason I was trying to properly understand how the code in K+R worked.

The qsort implementation here is for sorting arrays of pointers.
BTW: It also assumes that all pointers have the same size (and alignment) as void-pointers. That's the typical case but the C standard doesn't guarantee that.
As this is for sorting arrays of pointers, it can't be used for sorting arrays of int. As stated in the question, the swap function is problematic.
You may be able to change a few things in the code and use it to sort an array of int-pointers based on the pointed to value.
In main something like:
//int i_numbers[] = {INT_MAX, 5, 9, 4, 8, 3, 7, 10, 2, 1, 6, INT_MIN};
int a = 42;
int b = 100;
int c = 43;
int* i_numbers[] = {&a, &b, &c};

....

//qsort ((void **)i_numbers, 0, i_size -1, (int (*)(void *, void*))cmpstr);
qsort ((void **)i_numbers, 0, i_size -1, (int (*)(void *, void*))cmpint);

and in cmpint something like:
int cmpint (int *i_left, int *i_right)
{
    //printf ("%d %d\n", *i_left, *i_right);
    if (*i_left < *i_right) return -1;
    if (*i_left > *i_right) return 1;
    return 0;
}

and in prtint something like:
void prtint (int **array, size_t i_size)
{    
    size_t i_count;
    if (i_size > 0)
    {
        printf ("(%d", *array[0]);
        for (i_count = 1; i_count < i_size; i_count++)
            printf (", %d", *array[i_count]);
    }
    printf (")\n");    
}

I don't think this is guaranteed to work on all systems (due to the assumption on pointer size) but it works on my system. I get:
(42, 100, 43)
(42, 43, 100)

However, there is no way to use this qsort as a generic array sorting function as  the size of the elements isn't known by this qsort.
The standard qsort uses "size of element" and "number of elements" (instead of array indexes) to get it correct. That makes it possible to implement a generic swap function.

When you call qsort for integers, pass cmpint as the last argument. Now you are using cmpstr in both cases.

Elaborating on why this mistake caused the error the OP is seeing would flesh out and improve this answer.
